# Integrate bash function return values

Tags: bash

I have a function:

```
something() {
  if [ something ]; then
    echo "Something.";
    return 0;
  else
    echo "Not something.";
    return 1;
  fi
}
```

I call it in a loop, it actually validates some files and counts how many files were valid:

```
find . -type l | while read line ; do something "$line"; done
```

I need to count how many files were invalid, therefore how many times the function has returned `0`. I was thinking about this:

```
INVALID=0;
find . -type l | while read line ; do INVALID=$(($INVALID + something "$line")); done
```

Needless to say, bash doesn't buy it. Note a few things:

- The info within `something` must be print in `stdout`.
- The info print does not always correlate with file validity in my code. It's just info for the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value isn't directly available for arithmetic like that. You can either call the function then access `$?`, or branch based on the result of the function, like so:

```
INVALID=0
while IFS= read -r line; do
    something "$line" || ((++INVALID))
done < <(find . -type l)
```

Also note that you can't change variables inside a pipeline. Pipelines run in subshells and have their own copies of variables. You'll need to restructure the loop to run without a pipeline to have the changes to `$INVALID` stick: change `find | loop` to `loop < <(find)`.

It's also a good idea to use `read -r` to disable backslash escapes and clear out `$IFS` to handle lines with leading whitespace better.

Comment: The pipe runs the loop in a subshell, so the variable changes won't be seen in the original process.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for noting this, I'd have a bad time finding it out :) Any workarounds?

Comment: Please give me some advice how to *restructure the loop to run without a pipeline*. I am totally lost and running out of time :(

Comment: One last question I guess: Can you think of any reason that would cause the bash to end after or within the loop? I just copy pasted it and after it, there's `echo "Found $INVALID invalid links.";` It doesn't echo anything. You can [try it with the actual function](http://pastebin.com/qtMnBHK2).

Comment: @TomášZato Add `set -x` to the top of the script and see what you get when you run it.

Comment: I tested more. `exit` works so the bash doesn't stop after the while loop - only echo stops working. Why could that be happening? Does it happen to you too?

Comment: @EtanReisner Wow, that's handy. Thanks, I found the bug I guess.